# Stripe not returning error messages vis javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, stripe-payments

I've written up this javascript to return error messages from Stripe if theres an invalid card, declined, etc.  It doesn't return anything.  It does the one moment please.... and then reenables the button when there should show an error, but the error doesnt show.

```
$('#subscription-form button').on('click', function () {
    var form = $('#subscription-form');
    var submit = form.find('button');
    var submitInitialText = submit.text();

    submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('Just one moment....');

    Stripe.card.createToken(form, function (status, response) {
        var token;

        if (response.error) {
            form.find('.stripe-errors').text(response.error.message).show();
            submit.removeAttr('disabled');
            submit.text(submitInitialText);
        } else {
            token = response.id;
            form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="token">').val(token));
            form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```

This is my view. This is done in Laravel.  The errors should show up in that div

```
<div class="stripe-errors panel hide"></div>
```

my form

```
<form action="{{ URL::action('subscription-join') }}" method="post" id="subscription-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            Choose Plan
            <label>
            Chosen Plan:
            <select name="plan">
                <option value="small">Small ($9.99/month)</option>
                <option value="large">Large (14.99/month)</option>
            </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">

                @include('subscription.partials._card')

            <button class="button">Make payment</button>

        </div>
    </div>
    {{ Form::token() }}
</form>
```